# Google Apps Script: Compare two columns and do something if condition match in a any row of the range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm completely new is this thing of scripting/programming, so I'm sorry if I've made something really stupid below

The scenario:

In column "D" I pull stock prices from Google with =GOOGLEFINANCE(B2;"PRICE")
In column "K" I setup a value that I'm waiting the paper to reach

[Real sheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Rqs.png)

I've wrote (or at least I thing I did) a script (pasted below) that sends me an e-mail when "D" < "K". Actually it's working, but only for the first row. The trigger is correctly configured and working, since when in the first row the condition above is matched, I receive an e-mail.

What I need:

A script that reads the column "D" and compare it with the column "K", row by row. If "D" < "K" send me an e-mail **for each occurrence**. Preferably with the paper name in the subject, which is stored in column "B"
Something like: "Alert! Paper TAEE3 reched the value"

```
function PaperValue() {
  var valorAlertaRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Situação").getRange("K2:K16"); 
  var valorAlerta = valorAlertaRange.getValue();
  var valorAtualRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Situação").getRange("D2:D16"); 
  var valorAtual = valorAtualRange.getValue();
  if (valorAtual <= valorAlerta){
    var subject = 'VALOR DO ALERTA ATINGIDO!';
    var message = 'O valor da ação atingiu o preço definido no alerta;  
    MailApp.sendEmail("xxx@live.com", subject, message);
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information?

Comment: Sure! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M46Vicc8bRLMbcl4Mw1NT_ycjhM0uzsTLmKDWxWgxv4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function PaperValue() {
  var krg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Situação").getRange("K2:K16");
  var kvs = krg.getValues();
  var drg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Situação").getRange("D2:D16");
  var dvs = drg.getValues();
  var subject = 'VALOR DO ALERTA ATINGIDO!';
  var message = 'O valor da ação atingiu o preço definido no alerta';
  kvs.forEach((k, i) => {
    if (dvs[i][0] <= k[0] && MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {
      MailApp.sendEmail("xxx@live.com", subject, message);
    }
  });
}
```

#### Explanation:

[getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) returns a single (top-left) cell in the range. Because of this, it is only working for the first row. Use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and iterate instead.

Comment: Thank you, Cooper. This really worked (despite I'm not being able to understand the code lol)
I'm receiving alerts for any row

I've tried to add the paper name in the subject 
```
var brg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Situação").getRange("B2:B16");
  var bvs = brg.getValues();
  var subject = bvs + 'VALOR DO ALERTA ATINGIDO!';
```
But it haven't worked at all, bringing the whole content of column B

Is it possible? Like
Row 13 matched the condition, so in the subject we could have "B13 content + Price reached"

Comment: And  if you're unwilling to take the time to learn it you never will. Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: What is that you wish to do?  Do you wish to change the range?

Comment: I notice in your image that D and K seem to be strings rather than numbers.   Is that correct?

Comment: Actually I've tried to put the code into ` ` as suggested in the area below this text box, but haven't worked. I'll learn more about this, I swear  <br/>
D and K are formated as currency (BRL in this case). If possible, in the var "subject" I would like to have the content of column B, which is a string containing the stock name  <br/>
E.g. Row 3: if D reach 5,00 (the value in K), the e-mail should have "ENAT3" (column B content) in the subject, like "ENAT3 stock price reached"

Comment: @vacamaromba Please consider accepting this answer, as it solves your original question.